# Regex for just only numbers

Tags: regex

I haven't used regular expressions soo much, so I'm having difficulty . I want regex that only validates that the field contains digits, but that does not care about how many.

It should approve 77 and 2377? But do not approve 77.43 or xyz777.

How can I get this using regular expression? Is this expression `^[0-9]+$` ok or not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's OK. You can just use `^\d+$` for all it matters anyway.

Comment: @SomiMeer Which language/tool/flavor are you using?

Comment: How can i get this behaviour 2011 + 3 digits . example 2011999 or 2012999

Comment: but this 2011 can be 2012 if i hardcode in this expression. it wud not work for 2012 ,2013 right

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this regex is perfectly valid and does what you think it does, although if your regex engine supports this you could use `\d`, whichs stands for `[0-9]`.

Comment: `\d` might also match decimal digits in other scripts and does not need to be identical to `[0-9]`. In .NET for example it matches `0123456789٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩۰۱۲۳۴۵۶۷۸۹߀߁߂߃߄߅߆߇߈߉०१२३४५६७८९০১২৩৪৫৬৭৮৯੦੧੨੩੪੫੬੭੮੯૦૧૨૩૪૫૬૭૮૯୦୧୨୩୪୫୬୭୮୯௦௧௨௩௪௫௬௭௮௯౦౧౨౩౪౫౬౭౮౯೦೧೨೩೪೫೬೭೮
೯൦൧൨൩൪൫൬൭൮൯๐๑๒๓๔๕๖๗๘๙໐໑໒໓໔໕໖໗໘໙༠༡༢༣༤༥༦༧༨༩၀၁၂၃၄၅၆၇၈၉႐႑႒႓႔႕႖႗႘႙០១២៣៤៥៦៧៨៩᠐᠑᠒᠓᠔᠕᠖᠗᠘᠙᥆᥇᥈᥉᥊᥋᥌᥍᥎᥏᧐᧑᧒᧓᧔᧕᧖᧗᧘᧙᭐᭑᭒᭓᭔᭕᭖᭗᭘᭙᮰᮱᮲᮳᮴᮵᮶᮷
᮸᮹᱀᱁᱂᱃᱄᱅᱆᱇᱈᱉᱐᱑᱒᱓᱔᱕᱖᱗᱘᱙꘠꘡꘢꘣꘤꘥꘦꘧꘨꘩꣐꣑꣒꣓꣔꣕꣖꣗꣘꣙꤀꤁꤂꤃꤄꤅꤆꤇꤈꤉꩐꩑꩒꩓꩔꩕꩖꩗꩘꩙０１２３４５６７８９`

Answer (score 0):

A simpler regex would be to invert your match and check for non-digit numbers: `\D`.

Comment: wht u mean by invert ur match

Comment: Well, if you're doing a check like this: if (preg_match("/^\d$/") { ...}, you could change this to: if (!preg_match('/\D/')) { ... }, which translates to "If no non-digit numbers are found, then..."