# String to contain only digits

Tags: asp.net, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex for just only numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8502357/regex-for-just-only-numbers)
>   [Javascript regex for allowing only positive digits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9523521/javascript-regex-for-allowing-only-positive-digits)

How can I check whether a string contains only digits and it's not empty string?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you really tried searching answer for this question?

Comment: @Anubhava: I'm using a validator and the answer at the so called duplicate, namely ^[0-9]+$ allowed empty string and space. It was accepted as answer, however it's incorrect for my question, so nope, this question is not a duplicate of that.

Comment: @Anubhava: I've searched on google but all the regexes I've found allowed empty string and white character, so none of the solution I've found worked.

Comment: The responses given here by Meagar and on Anubhava's duplicate DO answer your question. If it is not working for you then you need to change your question; add more details. (What validator?)

Comment: @LajosArpad: Please provide some details on how this regex `^[0-9]+$` can match an empty string or space.

Comment: No regex implementation I've come across would match that pattern to a space or empty string. It must be a particular quirk of the tool that you are using.

Comment: @GenericJon, you might be right, I'm using the asp:RegularExpressionValidator in the markup of a page and it allows space and empty string. I don't know why if the regex is correct. I've solved my problem with a requiredfieldvalidator which doesn't allow space and empty string, however this is a workaround, not an answer to the question.

Comment: @Lajos Arpad, yes that *is* the answer.  Your regex does not allow spaces and empty strings, but `asp:RegularExpressionValidator` does (more accurately, it trims away the leading spaces, leaving an empty string, then it discovers that the field value has not changed from the initial value, so assumes it is valid.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Match against 1 or more digits, anchoring your regex at the beginning and end:

```
/^\d+$/
```

- `^` - anchor at the beginning of the string
- `\d` - match digits (alias for `[0-9]`
- `+` - match one or more of the preceding
- `$` - anchor at the end of the string

Comment: Thank you, but this accepts space and empty string.

Comment: No it doesn't. The regular expression I've written specifically cannot match empty strings or whitespace. How are you using it?

Comment: I'm using it through a asp:RegularExpressionValidator in the markup of a page but it behaves unexpectedly in the cases mentioned above.

Comment: Then the problem is with the `RegularExpressionValidator` and you should ask another question about that. The regular expression above cannot be improved on.

Answer (score 1):

Try using a [RequiredFieldValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.requiredfieldvalidator%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (which does not allow the field to be empty) instead of a RegularExpressionValidator (which does.)